# Stereographic Projection and Diffeomorphism

Tags: calculus, differential-topology, diffeomorphism, stereographic-projections

I am recently studying about stereographic projection and it is stated that the punctured 2-sphere $S^2\backslash \left\{0,0,1\right\}$ is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$. I want to prove this statement but I am stuck at proving the mapping is differentiable. May I have some helps?
Here is my work:

> From the construction of stereographic projection, it is clear that $f:S^2\backslash \left\{0,0,1\right\}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ defined by $$f(x,y,z)=\left(\dfrac{x}{1-z},\dfrac{y}{1-z},0\right)$$ is bijective.

Then, I cannot proceed to prove that $f$ and $f^{-1}$ are differentiable. How can I prove it?

Comment: $f$ supposedly maps to $\mathbb{R}^2$, however in the equation you have the output of $f$ being a vector with three components.

Comment: opps.... But was the mapping right? Maybe I just turn it to $\mathbb{R}^3$? Then, how should I proceed? Or it is actually not diffeomorphic?

Comment: The last component is extraneous. Remember that we are projecting onto the plane. Writing
$$f(x,y,z)=\left(\frac{x}{1-z},\frac{y}{1-z}\right)$$
Would be correct. As for differentiability, see [here](https://www.mathcounterexamples.net/differentiability-multivariable-real-functions-part1/). It would help us to answer your question if you showed some of the stuff you've tried so far so we can find any mistakes / give you some hints.